# Removing applied filter with KonvaJS

Tags: javascript, konvajs, react-konva, konvajs-reactjs

I'm applying filters to Konva.Image but couldn't find any way to remove those filters and return to original image.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable filters you can just clear cache:

```
image.clearCache();

// also you can do this if you want to remove filters
image.filters([]);
```